# Comparing average between prokect budget

Tags: sql

What is wrong with the following sql statement?

```
SELECT *
FROM Projects AS Pro
WHERE Pro.Proj_Budget > AVG(Pro.Proj_Budget);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have aggregation functions in the `where` which is not allowed.

Instead:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Projects P
WHERE P.Proj_Budget > (SELECT AVG(P2.Proj_Budget) FROM Projects P2);
```